# Confusing python yield behavior

Tags: python, generator, yield

I came across a funny behavior of `yield` today that I don't really understand. Here's my code:

```
def a():
    def b(x):
        print("entering b.")
        yield 0
        if x == 0:
            print("calling b.")
            b(x + 1)
            print("return from b.")
        print("leaving b.")

    for x in b(0):
        yield x

for x in a():
    print(x)
```

That outputs:

```
entering b.
0
calling b.
return from b.
leaving b.
```

What quite confuses me is that explicitly calling `b(x + 1)` does not call `b` (!), neither does Python give any error or exception.

Now, obviously the error in the code above is that `b(x + 1)` should really yield the value that `b` yields - so it should read something like:

```
for x in b(x + 1):
  yield x
```

Things work then.

Still, is this something with `yield` I should be aware of?

Comment: You might want `yield from b(x + 1)`

Comment: Calling `b` doesn't run the body. That doesn't change just because it's a recursive call.

Comment: When you say "calling `b(x + 1)` does not call `b`" where are you calling it from? If it is outside of `a` it doesn't get called because it is out of scope

Comment: I think this question is more about why the function call is not executed.

Comment: The function call *is* executed; the resulting generator is simply ignored.

Comment: Not sure if `print("calling b.")` is confusing you? And since you have no `yield` from your recursive call - that will also not return what you probably expect it to.. as snake points out.

Answer (score 5):

The `b(x + 1)` is called, but not executed until yielded in the context of the calling function.

Using `yield from` to yield all the values produced by that call to `b()` and execute the body:

```
def a():
    def b(x):
        print("entering b.")
        yield 0
        if x == 0:
            print("calling b.")
            yield from b(x + 1)
            print("return from b.")
        print("leaving b.")

    for x in b(0):
        yield x

for x in a():
    print(x)
```

Comment: I don't understand if b(x + 1) is called (without the `yield from`), then why "entering b." is not printed?

Comment: @handras because generators are lazy. It has been created but its code does not run until you attempt to get it's `next` element.

Comment: `b(x+1)` doesn't do anything except return a generator; you still have to *iterate* over that generator in order for the body to execute. That's the difference between `yield` and `return`.

Comment: @handras because that is *how generators are supposed to work*. It stops and re-starts exection of the body at yield statements, whenever a `next` is called. Often in the context of being iterated over.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer you got so far is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856232/1256452) (and I've upvoted it), but I see you're still fighting with this a bit, so let's try this variant:

```
def a():
    def b(x):
        print("entering b.")
        yield 0
        if x == 0:
            print("calling b.")
            temp = b(x + 1)
            print("calling b resulted in temp =", temp)
            print("return from b.")
        print("leaving b.")

    for x in b(0):
        yield x

for x in a():
    print(x)
```

Now let's run this in Python 3.x:

```
entering b.
0
calling b.
calling b resulted in temp = <generator object a.<locals>.b at 0x800ac9518>
return from b.
leaving b.
```

That is, `temp` is set to the result of calling `b(x + 1)`, and that *result* is this `<generator object ...>` thing.

You then have to do something *with* the generator object, so here is yet a third variant:

```
def a():
    def b(x):
        print("entering b.")
        yield 0
        if x == 0:
            print("calling b.")
            temp = b(x + 1)
            print("calling b resulted in temp =", temp)
            y = next(temp)
            print("by doing next(temp), I got", y)
            print("return from b.")
        print("leaving b.")

    for x in b(0):
        yield x

for x in a():
    print(x)
```

Running this produces:

```
entering b.
0
calling b.
calling b resulted in temp = <generator object a.<locals>.b at 0x800ac9518>
entering b.
by doing next(temp), I got 0
return from b.
leaving b.
```

The `yield from` variant in the other answer basically means "keep calling temp and yielding whatever it yields, until it says it's done".  This `y = next(temp)` called temp just once.

**Exercise for the reader:**  Try the fourth variant quoted below.  Try to predict, before you run it, what you'll see.  Do you see what you predicted?

```
def a():
    def b(x):
        print("entering b.")
        yield 0
        if x == 0:
            print("calling b.")
            temp = b(x + 1)
            print("calling b resulted in temp =", temp)
            y = next(temp)
            print("by doing next(temp), I got", y)
            try:
                print("about to re-enter temp")
                y = next(temp)
                print("with the second next(temp), I got", y)
            except StopIteration:
                print("with the second next(temp), I got StopIteration")
            print("return from b.")
        else:
            print("b had x =", x)
        print("leaving b.")

    for x in b(0):
        yield x

for x in a():
    print(x)
```